# Format number with javax.script

Tags: java

I've just upgraded to java 8. Previously I was using the nashorn script engine and the following would work:

```
engine.eval("format('%04d-%02d-%02d', 1966, 07, 18);");
```

Now I get:

```
<eval>:1 ReferenceError: "format" is not defined
```

I've googled around for over a day now, but I just can't find an example of this. Is this still supported?

Very grateful for any help.

Comment: Format is not a default function in javascript, you can prototype it of course.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense. Open chrome, for example, and see that format is not a globally available function and you'd get the exact same exception.

Take a look at this one:

[Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

You'd probably have to define the prototype of the format function if you want to use it like that.

And here is some sample code to get you started:

```
engine.eval(""
                + "var options = {year: \"numeric\", month: \"numeric\", day: \"numeric\"};"
                + "var res = new Date(1966, 07, 18).toLocaleDateString('en', options);"
                + "print(res);");
```

Also, some rather intriguing .md file where you can see the global stuff exposed in nashorn:

https://gist.github.com/WebReflection/9627010